# Using SharePoint to custom develop a GUI for an SQL Server backend?

Tags: sql, sharepoint

Is it possible to use use SharePoint to custom develop a GUI for an SQL Server backend for updating the data? Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic. Too broad. Unclear what you're asking. Dude I don't know how many close votes apply here. BTW yes, everything is possible with a computer (except to raise the dead, by now)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2007 you might want to take a look at the Business Data Catalogue  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661(v=office.12).aspx

Not sure what the comparable feature (if any) in 2010/2013 is...

EDIT:

In 2013 it is called Business Connectivity Services - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163782.aspx#BCSoverview_Whatcanbcsdo

Answer (score 0):

Look at "Business Connectivity Services" and "External List".

SharePoint Designer can make the process pretty simple or you can develop a Visual Studio project:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558778(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the legwork try building an Access Application in SharePoint 2013.

It is much better than 2010 but requires more setup. This will encapsulate a database within a SQL database, very versatile super quick and you can do all your SQL fun stuff from there.

This is a low or no code solution.

SharePoint 2010 Access apps use lists as back-end repositories, you can interact with the data in the SharePoint WSS_Content database, but it is not supported and no advisable.